# Large transaction log won't truncate

Tags: sql-server

I ran a full backup on SQL server 2008, but the transaction log stayed in tact. I though a full backup would make a new transaction log. What do I need to do to get my trn to a normal size?

Comment: `I though a full backup would make a new transaction log.` No. Did you read that somewhere?